# android - can't customize ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

Somehow I'm having a difficult time figuring out a seemingly easy problem. None of the attributes I specify, including `android:text`, `android:textSize`, `android:textColor`, `android:textAppearance`, seem to do anything to my ActionBar. When I run my project "MainActivity" on the ActionBar is still white and the default font size. I'm using API level 16.

Here's my styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:text">This String Is Not Showing Up In ActionBar!</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">44dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using ActionBar compatibility version (that can works for the older version)?

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

```
<item name="android:text">This String Is Not Showing Up In ActionBar!</item>
```

This won't work. <s>The actionbar title should be set using the activities label field in your manifest or by accessing the actionbar object in your activity.</s>

**UPDATE**: the struck out information was partially inaccurate. Turns out you *can* set the title of the actionbar in styles.xml with the android:title tag. Here is a more accurate solution:

```
 <style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:title">This String WILL show up in the ActionBar!</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">44dp</item>
</style>
```

**OLD ANSWER**:

To change the text style of the actionbar title ([titleTextStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#titleTextStyle)) you will need a new style:

```
<style name="Text.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">44dp</item>
</style>
```

and reference it from your actionbar style

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Text.ActionBar</item>        
</style>
```

For more information on the styles you can theme in the actionbar check out the [R.attr](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do similar things with the below code. PS - I used Appcompat but since you are using ApI 16 you can use the current ActionBar itself.

```
<!-- general styles for the action bar -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>

<!-- action bar title text -->
<style name="TitleTextStyle"  parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">100sp</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppCompatTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```